# What would be involved in Chucking out IB entirely?(monodevelop)

Tags: mono, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

It is my understanding that you dont really need IB. You can write your interface entirely in code.  Why doesnt mono and  monotouch produce a designer like that of visual studio  and sharp develop?

What would it take to implement that? Where would I start?

How many man hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not really practical to implement a UI designer. It's a LOT of work. MonoDevelop's Gtk# designer took 2 years to write, for example.

Since Xcode is still a requirement for MonoTouch development (e.g. gcc and other build tools), it's probably more practical to simply continue using Xcode's Interface Builder. However, perhaps there are ways to integrate it better into MonoDevelop.